# Merge [llm] and [large-language-model]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Tag [llm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/llm) has no description, and being three letter acronym most likely will have problems with ambiguity.

On the other hand, [large-language-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/large-language-model) is clear and has a tag info.

At the moment, there are no questions tagged with [llm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/llm) unrelated to large language models. This can be confirmed with the following search: [`[llm] -[chromadb] -[langchain] -[pytorch] -[artificial-intelligence] -[huggingface] is:q  -gpt -llama -openai collective:-"NLP"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bllm%5D%20-%5Bchromadb%5D%20-%5Blangchain%5D%20-%5Bpytorch%5D%20-%5Bartificial-intelligence%5D%20-%5Bhuggingface%5D%20is%3Aq%20%20-gpt%20-llama%20-openai%20collective%3A-%22NLP%22): 6 questions present are clearly AI/GPT related, and excluded tags and terms are also all related to the field.

I propose merging of [llm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/llm) into [large-language-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/large-language-model), with creation of corresponding synonym.